# multilevel user admin in django

Tags: python, django

Need to create multi level users with roles having same validation for the models as that specified in admin.py, only that each of these users will have different roles.eg. Customer can have different custom_users with diff. roles. A customer can create multiple such custom users with different roles. Each customer can see only his own records in the admin panel.  Models: Customer, Custom_user(customer f.key), Role(permission) , customer_customuser(custom_user_id,role_id), But I need to use the same permissions as available in the original django default admin panel for the diff.models like add,edit,delete, view. But have also customized it in admin.py such that each customer can administer using changelist_view and filtering the queryset objects accordingly. How can this be achieved. The models:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The Email field must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Specify a related_name below
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='custom_users')
    # # Specify a related_name for the groups below
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True,
                                    related_name='custom_users')

    # Add a custom related_name for user_permissions below
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        blank=True,
        related_name='custom_users_permissions'
    )

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    # class Meta:
    #     permissions = [
    #         ("can_view_custom_user", "Can view custom users"),
    #         # Define other permissions here as needed
    #         ("view_domain", "Can view domain"),
    #         ("add_domain", "Can add domain"),
    #         ("change_domain", "Can change domain")

    #     ]


# Create your models here.
class AbstractPerson(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[mobile_regex])
    muser_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


class Customer(AbstractPerson):
    #multiadmin line
    # Each Customer can have multiple CustomUser instances with different roles
    custom_users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser,
                                          through='CustomerCustomUser')
```

Roles should be the same as available in the default django users/groups

Comment: Can you provide a sample of models with code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to let every user go through the django admin panel? or Are you creating templates for admin panel separately?

Comment: allowing everyone to go thru admin panel. But customer cannot access django  authentication users/groups section. He needs to create the custom_users and roles with the registered models above and  provide the role based permissions.

Comment: I don't suggest letting everyone through the Django admin panel as it is prone to more risks. You can create your admin templates and different URLs for this purpose. You'll have more flexibility and control over the customers and admins and the risk factor can be reduced substantially.

Comment: @Anjaan I already have a system running with superuser having customers. Now I want  to incorporate the above models to add the multiadmin functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all edit your `Role` model to use Django's `Group` model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in your `admin.py` try to define the default roles and their permissions

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from .models import Role

admin.site.unregister(Group)

@admin.register(Role)
class RoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #create or update the associated group with the same name as the role
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=obj.name)
        obj.group = group
        obj.save()

        #assign the permissions to the group
        permissions = Permission.objects.filter(custom_users__role=obj)
        group.permissions.set(permissions)

        #update the associated custom users' groups
        custom_users = obj.custom_users.all()
        for custom_user in custom_users:
            custom_user.groups.add(group)
```

you have to also edit your `CustomUser` model to remove the `role` field and use the `groups` field instead

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #rest of your code

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True,
                                    related_name='custom_users')

    #rest of your code
```

and create a through model `CustomerCustomUser` to link `Customer` and `CustomUser` models

```
class CustomerCustomUser(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and finally edit your `Customer` model to use the `CustomerCustomUser` model

```
class Customer(AbstractPerson):
    custom_users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser,
                                          through=CustomerCustomUser)
```

and now each customer can have multiple custom users with different roles, and they will inherit the permissions assigned to their respective roles!

**UPDATE**

according to your comment, you can add a `related_name` argument to the `user_permissions` field in your `CustomUser` model, because it will give a unique reverse accessor name for the `user_permissions` field in your `CustomUser` model, and avoiding the clash with the `auth.User` model!

```
user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    Permission,
    blank=True,
    related_name='custom_user_permissions'
)
```

**UPDATE 2**

According to your comment, the error you are getting is because you are trying to assign a role to a CustomUser instance using an email address instead of a CustomUser instance itself,so please make sure that you are passing a CustomUser instance when assigning a role to a user

something like this :

```
custom_user = CustomUser.objects.get(email="m@y.com")
role = Role.objects.get(name="customer")
custom_user.role = role
custom_user.save()
```

**UPDATE 3**

according to your comment,to re-register the default `Group` model in the Django admin for the superuser,add this 3 lines into `admin.py`, because by calling `admin.site.register(Group)`, you are re-registering the `Group` model in the Django admin interface!

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

admin.site.register(Group)
```

Comment: all other definitions are fine ?

Comment: all above model definitions are fine which I have mentioned above?  I get error while adding role: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Cannot query "m@y.com": Must be "CustomUser" instance.

Comment: permissions = Permission.objects.filter(custom_users__role=obj)    happens at this line of save

Comment: `custom_users = obj.custom_users.all()   `   'Role' object has no attribute 'custom_users'

Comment: ..This works but the default Groups which is unregistered, that is also needed. How to reregister it in admin for superuser?